# how can i call getwallet function and filter list which has balance more than 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

Data is in nested object format which i am getting from an api and the data format is
{
"info": {
"makerCommission": "10",
"takerCommission": "10",
"buyerCommission": "0",
"sellerCommission": "0",
"canTrade": true,
"canWithdraw": true,
"canDeposit": true,
"updateTime": "1639767562245",
"accountType": "SPOT",
"balances": [
{
"asset": "BTC",
"free": 0.00000371,
"locked": 0.00000000
},
{
"asset": "LTC",
"free": 0.00000769,
"locked": 0.00000000
}
}

````
Passing a value info.balances in a function but it is giving an error. i can use object('info.balances') directly and access its data but i want to filter the data so i can get only those value which are greater than 0.

    ```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <title>Comment</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> -->
            
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <!-- CSS only -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
              
              
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
    
        <div class="main-body">
          <header>
    
    
    
            <div id="main">
              <table id="table_id" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                  <tr class="bg-dark">
                    <th class="grey">asset</th>
                    <th class="grey">free</th>
                    <th class="grey">locked</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
      
          <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    
    
          <script>
            function getWalletJSON(data) {
                console.log(46, data);
                let arr = data.filter(function(elem) {
                    console.log((elem.free > 0));
                return (elem.free > 0)
                });
            }
          </script>
        
          <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#table_id').DataTable( {
                    ajax: {
                        // url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments',
                        url: 'http://design.trailingcrypto.com/api/trade/balances?exchange=binance',
                        dataSrc: getWalletJSON(info.balances)
                    },
                    columns: [
                        // { data: 'asset'},
                        {   data: null,
                            orderable: false,
                            className: 'hvhb',
                            render: function (data, type, row, ){
                                let newdata ='';
                                //     if(data.free >= 1 ){
                                // //    console.log(data.asset);\
                                //  newdata = `${data.asset}`
                                // // return newdata;
                                //     }
                                //     return newdata;
                                if(data.free >0 ) newdata = newdata + `</br>(${data.asset})`;
                                console.log(newdata);
                                return newdata; 
                            }
                        },
                        // { data: 'free'},
                                
                        {   data: null,
                            orderable: false,
                            className: 'hvhb',
                            render: function (data, type, row, ){
                                // if(data.free >= 1 ){
                                //    console.log(data.free);
                                let newdata = `${data.free}`;
                                return newdata;
                            }
                                        
                        },
                                
                        // { data: 'locked'},
                    ]
                });
            })
          </script>
      </body>
    </html>
    ```
````

Comment: [Code samples](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should be *minimal*, complete and representative, and include error messages (if any); the linked document explains this and more. Make sure you format all sample data and code properly (as I've done for this question) for readability. You can also turn the sample into a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/90527).

Comment: Note the sample HTML is invalid, due to unclosed tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning anything from your `getWalletJSON` function. The `return` statement that you do have belongs to the `filter` function.

```js
function getWalletJSON(data) {
    console.log(46, data);
    let arr = data.filter(function(elem) {
        console.log((elem.free > 0));
        return (elem.free > 0)
    });
    return arr;
}
```